# Call child hook function from parent using refs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm switching over to building components using Hooks and i'm struggling to setup refs with `useRef()`

**Parent (The ref is only added to one component currently, as I'd like to ensure this is working before extending functionality to others)**:

```
export default function UserPanels({ selected_client } ) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
    const container = useRef( null );

    function handleChange(event, newValue) {
        setValue(newValue);
        container.current.displayData();
    }

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <UserTabs
                value={value}
                onChange={handleChange}
                indicatorColor="primary"
                textColor="primary"
                variant="fullWidth"
                aria-label="full width tabs example"
            >
                <Tab label='Service User' {...a11yProps(0)} />
                <Tab label='Care Plan' {...a11yProps(1)} />
                <Tab label='Contacts' {...a11yProps(2)} />
                <Tab label='Property' {...a11yProps(3)} />
                <Tab label='Schedule' {...a11yProps(4)} />
                <Tab label='Account' {...a11yProps(5)} />
                <Tab label='Invoices' {...a11yProps(6)} />
                <Tab label='Notes' {...a11yProps(7)} />
                <Tab label='eMAR' {...a11yProps(8)} />
            </UserTabs>
            <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
                <UserDetailsContainer
                    selected_client={ selected_client }
                />
            </TabPanel>
            <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
                Care Plan
            </TabPanel>
            <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
                <ContactsContainer
                    ref={ container }
                    selected_client={ selected_client }
                />
            </TabPanel>
            <TabPanel value={value} index={3}>
                Property
            </TabPanel>
            <TabPanel value={value} index={4}>
                Schedule
            </TabPanel>
            <TabPanel value={value} index={5}>
                Account
            </TabPanel>
            <TabPanel value={value} index={6}>
                Invoices
            </TabPanel>
            <TabPanel value={value} index={7}>
                Notes
            </TabPanel>
            <TabPanel value={value} index={8}>
                eMAR
            </TabPanel>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**Child:**

```
export default function ContactsContainer( props ) {
    const [ state, setState ] = useState({
        contact_records: contacts,
        data_ready: true
    });

    function displayData() {
        console.log( 'display time' );
    }

    if ( !state.data_ready ) return null

    return (
        <>
            {
                state.contact_records.map( ( contact ) => {
                    return <ContactRecord contact={ contact } />
                } )
            }
        </>
    )
}
```

Essentially, I'm trying to call a child function from the parent but `ref.current` evaluates to `null` and when `handleChange()` is invoked I receive the error `container.current is null` and I regularly see the error `Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?`

As a note, I've already tested `forwardRef`:

```
<ContactsContainer
    ref={ container }
    selected_client={ selected_client }
 />
```

And, while this removes the error, it does not solve the issue. I've never had an issue using refs with class components but I seem to be missing something here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, don't overuse `refs` ( [react doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#dont-overuse-refs)). You must not control your child component by call directly its functions (and honestly you can't do this with function components).

If you need to display something in your children, you have to prepare data in your parent component and pass that data by props. Children should be as simple as possible. They should get props and displaying some data.

In parent:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
const [time, setTime] = useState(null);
function handleChange(event, newValue) {
    setValue(newValue);
    setTime('display time');
}

return (
    ....
    <ContactsContainer
        time={time}
        selected_client={ selected_client }
     />
    ....
)
```

If you need to make some side effects (e.g. make HTTP calls, dispatch Redux actions) in your child when props changes, you have to use [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook.

In parent:

```
<ContactsContainer
    value={value}
    selected_client={ selected_client }
 />
```

In child:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('display time action');
}, [props.value]);
```

Comment: So this works by the tab (index) clicked matching the index of the child. So if i was to pass a `selected_index` down to each child and, when `selected_index` changes, check whether it matches the child and display some data if true, that would be the better option?

Comment: @AdamRoberts No. Displaying some data is not a side effect. If you just need to display data, you have to prepare it in your parent component and pass to children by props. I have updated an answer.

Comment: The data is generated from the child, but whether it's displayed is decided by the parent. Hard to explain but all sorted now - your original answer got me over the line, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you can pass a ref as a prop:

```
// ...
const infoRef=useRef(null)
useEffect(()=>{
    if(infoRef.current) infoRef.current()
},[])
return <ChildComponent infoRef={infoRef} />
```

and then in child:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    infoRef.current=childFunctionToExecuteInParent
},[])
```